# Essa pergunta pode ser considerada uma "pergunta camaleão"?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Hoje a tarde fiz uma pergunta relacionada a possibilidade da utilizar `traits` do php para resolver um problema específico.

[Forçar a declaração de propriedades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30867/for%C3%A7ar-a-declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-propriedades)

A partir dos comentários feitos na mesma, percebi que não fui muito claro em [minha dúvida inicial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/30867/2) e resolvi incluir mais detalhes incluindo um [exemplo do que já tentei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/30867/3).

Prontamente, minha pergunta foi apontada como sendo uma pergunta camaleão por um usuário que tinha postado uma resposta que não resolvia a questão inicial no meu ponto de vista.

Gostaria da opinião da comunidade: Essa pergunta se caracteriza como uma pergunta camaleão?
Caso seja unânime que sim, não vejo problema nenhum em retornar a pergunta pra edição original.

Comment: Curto e grosso: ***NÃO***. A edição não alterou o sentido, apenas acrescentou informação. A questão continua a mesma, apenas com mais algum exemplo do problema.

Comment: Não. E eu até parei de ajudar quando vi que a situação ia ficar ruim lá. A culpa não é sua. É um outro problema que as pessoas que podem, se recusam resolver. Você deu azar.

Comment: Engraçado, tomei downvotes ^^

Comment: @gmsantos, não tem muito jeito, tem que endurecer a couraça pois downvotes são parte intrinsica do site. E nos meta sites é grátis! Fica um -+1 virtual da minha parte :D

Comment: @PapaCharlie, acho que pode publicar seu comentário como resposta pois é isso mesmo: não houve alteração da pergunta original apenas adição de mais informações. Se uma resposta errônea foi postada é porque houve alguma falha na explicação da pergunta original, não porque o autor reformulou completamente a pergunta.

Comment: @brasofilo, eu até iniciei e ficou salva como rascunho... mas acabei pegando as primeiras linhas e deixando mais sucinto :) Preferem que jogue como resposta?

Comment: @PapaCharlie ao meu ver responde a pergunta

Comment: @gmsantos levou DOWN pois o tempo limite de votos passou e liberou os votos de quem não podia votar mais...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NÃO**.

Na questão citada, a edição não alterou o sentido, apenas acrescentou informação pertinentes. A questão continua a mesma, apenas com mais exemplo e descrição do problema.

*O [histórico de edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/30867/revisions) da questão mostra acréscimos e não remoções que alteram o sentido.*